# Estimation of the number of solutions by Counting

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing, counting, mathematical-programming, statistics

This is a question from a quantum computation textbook.

Consider a classical algorithm for counting the number of solutions to a problem. The algorithm samples uniformly and independently $k$ times from the Search Space of size $N$ for solutions using an Oracle that outputs 1 or 0, and let $X_1,X_2,X_3,...X_k$ be the results of the Oracle calls. So $X_j=1$ if the $jth$ Oracle call found a solution and $X_j=0$ otherwise. This algorithm estimates the number of solutions $S$:

> $$S=N * \sum_{j}\frac{X_j}{k}$$

Assuming the number of solutions is $M$ and this is not known in advance. The Standard Deviation of $S$ is stated and found to be:

> $$\Delta S=\sqrt{\frac{M(N-M)}{k}}$$

**The question is:**
Prove that to obtain a probability at least $\frac{3}{4}$ of estimating $M$ correctly to within an accuracy $\sqrt{M}$ for all values of $M$, we must have $k=\Omega(N)$.

I know how to get the 2nd equation from the 1st, which is by moving $N$ and $k$ to the left, thus treating $kS/N$ as a Binomial Distribution $B(k,\frac{M}{N})$. Then finding the variance of the Binomial Distribution and some algebraic manipulation will lead to the 2nd equation. I'm clueless in proving of $k=\Omega(N)$. Only thing I tried writing is:

> $$P\Big(\sqrt{\frac{M(N-M)}{k}}\leq \sqrt{M}\Big)\geq \frac{3}{4}$$

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You need an anti-concentration result such as [Paley-Zygmund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That looks complicated. Are you able to show me how to apply it in this context?

Comment: It's your exercise. You should give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a binomial random variable $X \sim \mathrm{bin}(n,p)$, and let $Y = (X - pn)^2$. [A straightforward but long calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142437/how-to-calculate-the-4th-central-moment-of-binomial-distribution) shows that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y]^2}{\mathbb{E}[Y^2]} =
\frac{np(1-p)}{p^3 + (1-p)^3 + 3(n-1)p(1-p)} = \frac{1}{3} + o(1).
$$
(This is to be expected, since a binomial random variable has roughly Gaussian distribution, and for Gaussian distributions the ratio is exactly $1/3$.)

Now let $Z = (S - M)^2$. It is still the case that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[Z]^2}{\mathbb{E}[Z^2]} = \frac{1}{3} + o(1),
$$
since $Z$ is just a scalar multiple of $Y$ above, for an appropriate choice of parameters.

In view of applying the Paley–Zygmund inequality, let us estimate
$$
\theta = \frac{M}{\mathbb{E}[Z]} = \frac{M}{M(N-M)/k} = \frac{k}{N-M}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\Pr[|S-M| > \sqrt{M}] = \Pr[Z > M] \geq (1-\theta)^2 \left(\frac{1}{3} + o(1)\right).
$$
If we want the right-hand side to be bounded by some constant (in your case, $1/4$) then we need $\theta$ to be bounded from below by some constant $c$ (in your case, roughly $1-\sqrt{3/4}$). In other words, we need
$$
k = \theta (N-M) = \Omega(N-M).
$$
As long as $M$ is not very close to $N$, this is $\Omega(N)$.

(When $M$ is very close to $N$, less samples are needed. For example, only one sample is needed when $M = N$.)

Comment: Wow.. Thank you for sharing the solution in this clear manner. My aptitude in math is not yet mature to this level. Haha I don't think I would have figure out these steps myself.

Comment: Just one more clarification. Shouldn't it be $P(|S-M|\leq\sqrt{M})$ since the estimate $S$ must be within $\pm\sqrt{M}$ of $M$?

Comment: I'll let you work that out. It's part of understanding the solution.

Comment: If we were to stick with $Pr(|S-M| > \sqrt{M})$ and we let the right side be bounded by the constant $1/4$, then shouldn't the inequality between $Pr()$ and $1/4$ be $<$? How are we going to apply the Paley-Zygmund Theorem?

Comment: I suggest you spend a few hours thinking it through.

Comment: So its $1/4 > Pr(|S-M| > \sqrt{M}) \geq (1-\theta)^2 (\frac{1}{3}+o(1))$. Thats what you meant by "...the right-hand side to be bounded by some constant..."

Comment: Hi, did I get it right this time? I really want to know so that I can move on to my other stuffs. Don't want this to keep bugging me.

Comment: Real understanding is when you can tell whether you’re right or wrong.

Comment: The theorem only says that $Pr()$ can be low-bounded from below if we choose some value of $k$. If we upper-bound the right hand side by lower-bounding $k$, how is it that this upper-bound will also be able to upper-bound $Pr()$? If we apply the theorem to values of $k$ which are above the lower-bound value, we'll only know that $Pr()$ will be lower-bounded by an even smaller value. Are you able to give hints?

Comment: It's really best if you worked it out on your own. It seems things are still not "clicking". Eventually they will.